# MongoDB query on nested array

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection containing documents like this:

```
"_id" : "d0888171-473d-46c7-a9c2-e18dfa141998",
"NUMBER" : 111111,
"SECURITIES" : [ 
    {
        "FK_GROUPS_ID" : ObjectId("59d4e02540b8f85428c827f9"),
        "ACCESS_LEVEL" : "r"
    }, 
    {
        "FK_GROUPS_ID" : ObjectId("59d24bce184fcd62968a21a3"),
        "ACCESS_LEVEL" : "rw"
    }
]
```

}

How to find all documents with a specific FK_GROUPS_ID in SECURITIES array?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({'SECURITIES.FK_GROUPS_ID' : ObjectId("GroupsIdString")});
```